# expectation of a product of a brownian motion and a poisson process

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, poisson-process

I am trying to find out the expectation $\mathbb{E}[X_t|\mathcal{F}_s]$ for
$$X_t = (W_tN_t)^n$$
where $n\geq 1$, $N_t$ is a homogenous poisson process with intensity $\lambda$ and $\mathcal{F}_s$ represents the information generated by both the brownian motion and the jump process up to time s. I thought I could proceed using Ito's lemma for jump processes, however I am not sure how to apply it in this particular case.

Comment: For which sigma-algebra?

Comment: The conditioning should be on the information generated by both the brownian motion and the jump process up to time s.

Comment: The sigma-algebra in your comment and the sigma-algebra mentioned in your question are not the same, a priori. Which one do you actually mean?

Comment: Edited, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: So, if $n=1$, $$X_t=(W_s+Z)(N_s+M)=W_sN_s+ZN_s+W_sM+ZM$$ for random variables $(Z,M)$ with known distribution and independent of $\mathcal F_s$, hence $$E(X_t\mid\mathcal F_s)=W_sN_s+E(Z)N_s+W_sE(M)+E(ZM)$$ Can you conclude in this case, and generalize the approach?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that $t\geq s$
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}(X_t|\mathcal{F}_s) &= \mathbb{E}\left[(W_t-W_s+W_s)^n (N_t - N_s+N_s)^n\right|\mathcal{F}_s] \\
&= \mathbb{E}\left[ \sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{j}(W_t - W_s)^{n-k}W_s^k\ \sum_{j=0}^n\binom{n}{k}(N_t - N_s)^{n-j}N_s^j \right]\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^n\sum_{j=0}^n \binom{n}{k} \binom{n}{j} W_s^k N_s^j    \mathbb{E}\left[ \left( W_t-W_s\right)^{n-k} \left( N_t - N_s\right)^{n-j} \right]
\end{align}
Furthermore, if the Poisson process is independent of the Brownian motion the last expectation becomes a product of two expectations of random variables whose distributions are known.